# Expectation of the Limit of a Sequence of Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Suppose that we have a sequence of random variables ${X_n}$ with the property that

$$
\mathbb{P}\Big( \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n = 0 \Big) = 1.
$$

My intuition from this equation is that the event

$$A = \Big\{ \omega \in \Omega | \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(\omega) = 0 \Big\}$$

is a high probability set. In an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4812411/an-infinite-gambling-game-and-the-money-left), I encountered  that it follows

$$
\mathbb{E}\Big( \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n \Big) = 0.
$$

However, I couldn't truely understand why this happens. I do not know much about measure theory and its applications in probability, so it would be nice if you could explain this in terms of basic mathematical analysis or at least a minimal amount of measure theory supported by some analysis and intuition. Another natural question is that what can we say about the cardinality of $A$?

Comment: @Sarilass That's an argument in favor not being able to exchange limit and integral. Right now the question is why $E(\lim X_n)=0$.

Comment: @Sarilass Is $n$ a constant in your example, or you meant $\mathbb{P}(X_n=n)=\frac{1}{n}$? In either case, if the $X_n$ are independent then from the second Borel-Cantelli lemma it's not hard to deduce that $X_n$ can't tend to $0$ almost surely. On the other hand, if you want $\mathbb{P}(X_n=n^2)=\frac{1}{n^2}$ then yes, $X_n\to 0$ almost surely by the first Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: For OP question, I think it is hard to show this in basic mathematical analysis without measure theory. Essentially, what OP asks is the implication $$ \mathbb{P}(X  = 0) = 1 \Longrightarrow \mathbb{E}(X) = 0$$ The proof of this will involve the fact that expectation of a random variable over a null set is $0$, i.e a basic fact of measure theory.

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn: OK, then please use a minimal amount of measure theory supported by some basi analysis. :)

Comment: The conclusion $\mathbb{E}\Big( \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n \Big) = 0$ is correct.  But beware!   The alternate conclusion $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}\Big(  X_n \Big) = 0$ may fail.

Comment: It seems to me that it is better to state that for every random variable $Y$ on the space we have $\mathbb EY=0$ if $Y$ coincides wth $\lim X_n$ on the set $\{(X_n)_n\text{ is convergent}\}$. This set has probability $1$ but is not necessarily the whole set $\Omega$ and if it is not then $\lim X_n$ is not formally a random variable (hence has no expectation).

Comment: @drhab: Hmmm, I agree. Do we have to say that $Y$ should be bounded on the set where $(X_n)$ is not convergent?

Comment: No, we do not need any further restrictions on random variable $Y$.

Answer (score 3):

Denote $\lim X_n = Y$ (1). Since the $X_n$ are measurable, $Y$ is also measurable. By assumption $\mathbb P\{Y=0\}=1$. Then
$$ EY = \int _{\{Y=0\}}Yd\mathbb P + \int _{\{Y\neq 0\}}Yd\mathbb P = 0. $$
In the first case, we integrate zero and in the second case we [integrate over a set of size zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922096/integral-over-set-of-measure-zero). In both cases, the result is zero.

---

You have tagged probability theory, so one cannot feasibly hope to dodge measure theory.

As for cardinality, it depends on $\Omega$. E.g if $\Omega =[0,1]$, which is uncountable, and $\mathbb P$ is the Lebesgue measure, then any event with positive measure would have to be uncountable.

---

(1) It is fair to point out that $Y(\omega)$ need not be defined because the limit might not exist. For this particular discussion, it does not pose a problem because by assumption, the subset of those $\omega$ for which $Y(\omega)$ is not defined is negligible (i.e contained in a measure zero subset). So we could set
$$ Y(\omega) = \begin{cases}\lim X_n(\omega), &\exists \lim X_n(\omega) \\ +\infty, &\text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Comment: "So we could set..." It may be nice to discuss complete probability spaces here

Answer (score 1):

Here is the continuation of my comment. Essentially, what we want to show is the following: For a random variable $X$,
$$
     \mathbb{P}(X = 0) = 1 \Longrightarrow \mathbb{E}(X) = 0
$$
To prove this, we split the random variable $X$ into two:
$$
     X = X \cdot 1\{X = 0\} + X \cdot 1\{X \neq 0\}
$$
where $1\{A\}$ is the indicator function of some event $A$. By linearity of expectation,
$$
    \mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X \cdot 1\{X = 0\}) + \mathbb{E}(X \cdot 1\{X \neq 0\})
$$
Now, consider the first expectation of $X \cdot 1\{X = 0\}$. Since $X(\omega) \cdot 1\{X = 0\}(\omega)$ equals to $0$, no matter what is the value of $\omega \in \Omega$, therefore, $X \cdot 1\{X = 0\} \equiv 0$, and
$$
    \mathbb{E}(X \cdot 1\{X = 0\}) = \mathbb{E}(0) = 0
$$
So,
$$
    \mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X \cdot 1\{X \neq 0\})
$$
Since $\mathbb{P}(X = 0) = 1$, we have $\mathbb{P}(X \neq 0) = 0$. Thus, the right hand side is the expectation of a random variable on a null set and this must be $0$ too (the proof of this fact [can be found here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293801/integral-over-null-set-is-zero), which is based on measure theory)

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a fundamental consequence of the definition of the Lebesgue integral, and so one cannot avoid this definition, and hence one cannot avoid measure theory in actually showing this.

---

Here's the standard development:

1. A nonnegative simple random variable is (roughly) one that only takes a finite number of nonnegative values, each of which is finite. More precisely, these are maps of the form  $$U(\omega) = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i \mathbf{1}_{E_i}(\omega),$$ where the $E_i$ are disjoint events, $a_i \in [0, \infty),$ and $n < \infty$. The idea is that its easy to define the integral of simple RVs by basically thinking about linearity: $\mathbb{E}[U] = \sum a_i P(E_i).$
2. For a non-negative random variable $X$, the expectation is *defined* as $$\mathbb{E}[X] := \sup\{\mathbb{E}[U] : U \le X, U \textrm{ simple, nonnegative}\}.$$ While the above is certainly well defined, it is not obvious that this matches your usual sense of the expectation: e.g., if the RVs have a nice density (what does that even mean, in the measure theoretic sense?), then does this definition yield $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int x f_X(x) \mathrm{d}x$? I'll leave it to you to consult an appropriate textbook for actually understanding this definition.
3. Proposition: If a random variable $X \ge 0$ satisfies $P(X = 0) = 1,$ then $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$.

> Pf. Let $E = \{\omega: X(\omega) \neq 0\}$. For any simple function $ U  = \sum_{i \le n} a_i \mathbf{1}_{E_i},$ if $U \le X,$ then for any $i : a_i > 0, E_i \subset E,$ and so $P(E_i) = 0.$ It thus follows that $\mathbb{E}[U] = \sum_{i } a_i P(E_i) = \sum_{i : a_i \le 0} a_i P(E_i) = 0$. But then $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is a supremum of the singleton set $\{0\},$ and so equals $0$.

---

There are now two complications in the case of your question:

For general random variables, the definition of integrals needs to consider the positive and negative parts separately. However, when dealing with $P(X = 0) = 1,$ we can simply deal with the nonnegative random variable $|X|$ instead, since $x = 0 \iff |x| = 0$, and since $|\mathbb{E}[X]| \le \mathbb{E}[|X|]$. So, in the following, lets set $Y_n(\omega) = |X_n(\omega)|$. Of course, by continuity, $X_n(\omega) \to x \implies Y_n(\omega) \to |x|$.

A final complication in the situation of the question is that we don't know that $\lim Y_n(\omega)$ is a random variable, since this may not exist for some $\omega$. Here the almost sure convergence lets us avoid this issue: pick any random variable $Z,$ and let us define $$ Y(\omega) = \begin{cases} \lim Y_n(\omega) & \lim Y_n(\omega) \textrm{ exists } \\ Z(\omega) & \lim Y_n(\omega) \textrm{ doesn't exist}\end{cases}.$$ Since $P(\lim Y_n = 0)  =1,$ no matter what $Z$ we pick, we also have $P(Y = 0) = 1.$ The technical term is that each such $Y$ is a *version* of $\lim Y_n$.

But now, for any version, since $Y \ge 0, P(Y = 0) = 1,$ the conclusion that $\mathbb{E}[Y] = 0$ follows from the proposition above. This controls $\mathbb{E}[\lim X_n]$ (or again, any version of this) to have mean $0$ using $0 \le |\mathbb{E}[\lim X_n]|\le \mathbb{E}[Y] = 0.$

Comment: How did you conclude the inequality in the last line?

Comment: Can we make the argument more concrete for [this sample space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4812411/an-infinite-gambling-game-and-the-money-left) which is not really a continuum?

Comment: The quickest way to see $|\mathbb{E}[X]| \le \mathbb{E}[|X|]$ is via Jensen's inequality. More directly, define $X^+ = \max(X,0), X^- = \max(-X,0),$ both of which are nonnegative. Then $|X| = X^+ + X^-, X = X^+ - X^-.$ So $|\mathbb{E}[X]| = |\mathbb{E}[X^+] - \mathbb{E}[X^-]| \le \max(\mathbb{E}[X^+], \mathbb{E}[X^-]) \le \mathbb{E}[X^+] + \mathbb{E}[X^-] = \mathbb{E}[|X|]$ (where we are using that for positive $a,b, |a-b| \le \max(a,b)$).

Comment: As for your sample space in the linked question, this definitely is a set of size continuum: map $\omega \mapsto \sum_i \mathbf{1}_{\{H\}}(\omega_i) 2^{-i}$. Then you generate every real number in $[0,1]$ (basically $H$ or $T$ corresponding to $1$ or $0$ in the binary expansion of the number).

Comment: About the inequality, I mean $0 \le |\mathbb{E}[\lim X_n]|\le \mathbb{E}[Y]$. I am not sure that it really makes sense to talk about $\mathbb{E}(\lim X_n)$ as $\lim X_n$ is not really defined over all of $\Omega$ as you also pointed out and so it is not a random variable.

Comment: Oh, like I said in the parentheses, it's really for any version of this, since the object is not well defined. Strictly speaking, we I guess we should start by defining a version of $\lim X_n$, and extend that to a version of $\lim Y_n$, and then use the above, but I guess I wrote the two bits in the opposite direction and missed this.

Comment: Whenever you got time, please fix the things you mentioned in your last comment. Then, I will accept your answer. Thanks for all the time you put in. :)